# How to use Paperclip with image_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I've been using Paperclip with my app in several models, but the following is giving me problems:

In the model:

```
has_attached_file :image, :path => (Rails.root + "document_libraries/:id/filename").to_s, 
                          :url => "/document_libraries/:id"
```

And in the view:

```
<%= image_tag(@document_library.image.url) if @document_library.image? %>
```

This shows the 'missing image' graphic in the browser.  What am I doing wrong here?  I can't have the images in my public directory.   I have a different model with this code, and it works perfectly:

```
has_attached_file :file, :path => (Rails.root + "team_photos/:id/:filename").to_s,
                         :url => "/team_photos/:id"

image_tag(@team_photo.file.url)
```

I have checked that the document_libraries folder exists in the rails root, and the actual jpg exists for the particular record I'm working with.  The permissions are the same as the team_photo model, which works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the difference, one `:` is missing

```
:path => (Rails.root + "document_libraries/:id/filename").to_s
```

and

```
:path => (Rails.root + "team_photos/:id/:filename").to_s
```

Comment: That didn't do the trick.  Besides, why does the same url scheme work for the other model?

Comment: Yes, I can see now. This is not the problem, but you left a `:` before your `filename` in the path. This is the difference between.

Comment: I thought that was it.  But after adding the colon, it still doesn't show the image, even after a server restart....